# how to remove string after specific character in list

Tags: list, c#-4.0

I have a list as given below.

```
List<string> testing = new List<string>();
            testing.Add("1(1)(r)");
            testing.Add("2(4)");
            testing.Add("3(w)");
            testing.Add("33(4)");
            testing.Add("5(4)");
            testing.Add("6(6)");
```

Now my problem is that i want to remove full string on or after "(" my list should be something like as given below.

```
1
2
3
33
5
6
```

How can i solve this problem with lambda expression or is ther any other way to remove string after some specific character.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
var result =  testing.Select(x => x.Split('(')[0]);
```

Another way:

```
var result =  testing.Select(x => x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf('(')));
```

Second approach will throw exception if one of your strings doesn't contain any `(`